# Can I use Programmatic Injection on the popup HTML page of a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

As the title suggests I am trying to use a content script or any other means of programatic injection to manipulate the website displayed within an iframe, that is located within the popup HTML file of my chrome extension.  The src of the iframe will be a 3rd party website.

The way that I typically execute a content script from the background page of a chrome extension is as follows:

```
//background.js

chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: "xxx", 
    contexts:["page"],
    id: "ctx1"
});
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info,tab) {
     if(infoItemId === "ctx1"){
         console.log("control worked")
         control(info,tab)  
     }
});
function control(info,tab) {
   chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,{file:"content.js"});
}
```

or

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(tab) +"\n\n")
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{"file":"content.js"});
})
```

I can access the iframe from the background page with the following code:

```
var views = chrome.extension.getViews({type:'popup'});
var iframe = views[0].document.getElementById("Frame1") // "Frame1" id the id of my iframe HTML element as declared in my popup.html file
```

I am unsure how to reconfigure my background page so that the iframe in my popup.html page will be targeted instead of the active browser tab.  I was thinking that I need to change the "contexts" attribute of the context menu to "frames" or "browser_action" and that I may need to create a new tab with the same url as my popup.html file.  I have spent a long time working on this problem and have made virtually zero progress, so any help would be greatly appreciated.